# How to remove "max-age" parameter from the Cache headers in PHP?

Tags: php, caching, browser-cache

How can I remove the `max-age` parameter from the Cache headers in PHP?

If I comment out the `session.cache_expire` variable in `PHP.ini`, it just sets max-age to 10800.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
session_cache_expire(0);
```

or if you want to remove caching, use:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

Comment: I don't want to remove caching, I just need to remove the max-age parameter.  `session_cache_expire(0);` will just set `max-age=0`, it does not remove it.

Comment: Not sure why you want to do that, but this might help.. 
http://serverfault.com/questions/295982/htaccess-how-to-remove-cache-controls-max-age